# Xml based bean creation possible wiht RoboGuice?

Tags: android, spring, dependency-injection, roboguice

I want to define beans into xml file and want to inject it using [RoboGuice](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/wiki) in android app, is it possible with RoboGuice?

Answer (score 0):

I believe, the answer is **NO**.

---

Though you can inject objects of simple types. A simple example:

Place this in your `res/values` folder:

```
<resources>
    <item name="flag" type="bool">false</item>
</resources>
```

And this in your `res/values-land` folder:

```
<resources>
    <item name="flag" type="bool">true</item>
</resources>
```

In your activity:

```
@InjectResource(R.bool.flag) private Boolean flag;
```

Now you can use `flag` to determine whether device is in landscape mode.